# How to assign variables taken from url to table (HTML, PHP)

Tags: php, html, css

Trying to assign variables set by user in URL to a table in HTML using php but it doesn't seem to work.

At start of body:

```
<?php
  $border = $_GET['border'];
  $cellpadding = $_GET['cellpadding'];
  $bgcolor = $_GET['bgcolor'];

?>
```

Below, in table:

```
<table <?php echo" style='border: $border; padding: $cellpadding; background-color: $bgcolor;' "; ?> >
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

This code is the same and I don't think that there's a problem with your code
But I prefer displaying PHP in HTML like that. If it does not work open `inspect element` and check the HTML code there and post it here

```
<table style="border:<?=$border?>; padding:<?=$cellpadding?>; background-color:<?=$bgcolor?>;">
```

Comment: I see. Is there any other code that you have to see that might be a source of error?

Comment: The input itself! the input of the user at the URL.
Post anything you're trying here, please

Comment: This is the url: https://url.php?x=0&y=3&z=2323&title=test&border=2px... nevermind x y z and title those are spare variables that actually work.

Comment: but the border won't work until you give it a color and style 
so you should first declare this in CSS
table{ border-style:solid; border-color:#333;}

Comment: It does, I have written border: 1px solid black; unless this doesn't work.

Comment: please post a screenshot of your page with URL